# How do I interpret this partial function syntax in f#?

Tags: f#

I am reading f# code and I am confused by the syntax. A Parser type is introduced as follows:

```
type Parser<'r> = Parser of (char list -> ('r*char list) list)
```

This is evaluated by the interpreter as:

```
type Parser<'r> = | Parser of (char list -> ('r * char list) list)
```

which makes sense to me. Then, a new line of code is introduced: 'A parser function also needs to be applied so we define a partial function for that:', and the code that follows:

```
let parse (Parser p) = p
```

and the interpreter output is:

```
Parser<'a> -> (char list -> ('a * char list) list)
```

I am surprised this is even valid syntax. What is it and why is it needed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general

`let f`*pattern*`=`*body*

is equivalent to

`let f = function`
`|`*pattern* `->`*body*

or, even more verbosely,

`let f x =`
    `match x with`
    `|`*pattern*`->`*body*

This allows you to avoid introducing a new identifier which is immediately destructured and then never used again.

In this particular example, that means that `parse` is equivalent to:

```
let parse x = 
    match x with
    | Parser p -> p
```

Since there is only a single case in the `Parser` type, this destructuring will always succeed.

Comment: Many thanks, upvoted and accepted as the answer. I did not know the notation used is shorthand for a pattern matching expression with the function being bound to p. (Pattern p) did not make sense, I thought it should have been (p:Pattern) or something, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily interprete these types if you understand the type of `(char list -> ('r*char list) list)` as a black box.

Suppose we have a type abbreviation:

```
type R<'r> = char list -> ('r*char list) list
```

Then `Parser<'r>` could be written as:

```
type Parser<'r> = Parser of R<'r>
```

When you declare a function:

```
let parse (Parser p) = p
```

the type checker infers the parameter of type `Parser<'r>` (by looking into the structure of `Parser p`). Therefore, the return value `p` obviously has type of `R<'r>`:

```
val parse : Parser<'a> -> R<'a>
```

Hypothetically, substituting `R<'r>` by its real declaration:

```
val parse : Parser<'r> -> (char list -> ('r*char list) list)
```

So the types inferred here totally make sense.